# Josephus problem using a linked list using malloc

Tags: c, linked-list, josephus

I'm planning to solve the Josephus problem in C using a linked list, but it doesn't work. I've tried multiple ways to do it, so I'm confused.

```c
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

struct Node {
    int num;
    struct Node *Next;
};

typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;

int main() {
    int n, m, i;
    PtrToNode p, q;

    printf("Please input n, m\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    p = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p->num = 1;
    p->Next = p;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        q = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        q->num = i;
        q->Next = p;
        p->Next = q;
        p = q;
    }

    while (q->Next != q) {
        for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
            p = q->Next;
        q = p;
        printf("%d, ", q->num);
        p->Next = NULL;
        free(q);
    }
    printf("%d\n", p->num);
    free(p);
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I kind of understand the struct function and the typedef, so I guess I don't have any problem there (?). I'm guessing I made a mistake in the main function.

Comment: `p->Next = p;` is probably not going to be correct. Also assigning twice to something will make the first assignment moot. I recommend you take a few steps back, get a pencil and some paper, and draw out your list operations on the paper using boxes for nodes (and other variables) and arrows for pointers. Write down a list of operations while erasing and redrawing arrows following those operations. Once it all seems to work on paper, implement it in code, but only a little bit at a time with plenty of testing in between.

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the typedef.  It does not provide any clarity and serves only to obfuscate.  Also, try to eliminate the special handling of the first element of the list.  Initialize the head of the list to NULL and give it values in the same loop as the other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues:

- The following assignments in the first loop create a cycle that *always* has length 2:

  ```
  q->Next = p;
  p->Next = q;
  ```

  The intention was to link back to the *first* node, but you don't have a reference to the first node anymore, only the previous (`p`). So introduce another variable that will not move: `head`, and then link back with `q->next=head`. And actually you can do that *after* the loop, just for the last node that was added.
- In the next loop, inside the `for` loop, the following will do the *same* thing in each iteration:

  ```
  p = q->Next;
  ```

  Since `q` is not moving, this just results in the same value being assigned to `p` in each iteration. It would make more sense to do `q = q->Next`
- Your code does not properly *detach* the node that is going to be deleted. It merely *ends* the list there:

  ```
  p->Next = NULL;
  ```

  This does not take into account that there is a node preceding `p` that is still referencing `p`. It is actually *that* preceding node that needs to be rewired. So you will actually want the preceding loop to stop one step earlier, so you have the reference to the preceding node `q`, and then do:

  ```
  p = q->Next; // p will be deleted
  q->Next = p->Next; // Rewiring around p
  ```

Here is the corrected `main`:

```
int main() {
    int n, m, i;
    PtrToNode head, p, q;

    printf("Please input n, m\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    printf("Input was n=%d, m=%d\n", n, m);

    head = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->num = 1;

    p = head;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        q = (PtrToNode)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        q->num = i;
        p->Next = q;
        p = q;
    }
    p->Next = head;

    while (q->Next != q) {
        for (i = 1; i < m; i++)
            q = q->Next;
        p = q->Next;
        printf("%d, ", p->num);
        q->Next = p->Next;
        free(p);
    }
    printf("%d\n", q->num);
    free(q);
    return 0;
}
```